# JavaScript - - Class Design pattern to Delegation Design pattern, new Constructor to Object.create()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert JavaScript Class Design Pattern to Delegation Design Pattern. (You Don't Know JS Series by Kyle Simpson)

I am not able to change the `new Constructor` to `Object.create()` in `[Symbol.iterator]` function of **Matrix object** of my Delegation Design code. I am not able setup a proper iterator for `for of` loop.

I am working with the Matrix Iterator code in Eloquent JavaScript book, Section: [Iterable Interface Section](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html). You can find the proper code in the link.

Nevertheless, I have Included the same code below.

**Class Design Pattern** Code as in the Link:

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  }

  get(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
  }
  set(x, y, value) {
    this.content[y * this.width + x] = value;
  }
}

class MatrixIterator {
  constructor(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true};

    let value = {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)
    };
    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return {value, done: false};
  }
}

Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return new MatrixIterator(this);
};

let matrix = new Matrix(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);
for (let {x, y, value} of matrix) {
  console.log(x, y, value);
}
```

**Delegation Pattern Code** that I am trying to create:

```
var Matrix = {
  init: function(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for(let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for(let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  },

  [Symbol.iterator]: function() {
    var matrixIt = Object.create(MatrixIterator);
    ????????? // **I have no clue what to do here, or even if I am right upto this point**
  },

  get: function(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
  },

  set: function(x, y, value) {
    this.content[y * this.width + x] = value;
  },
}

var MatrixIterator = Object.create(Matrix);

MatrixIterator = {
  setup: function(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  },

  next: function() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true};

    let value = {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)
    };
    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return {value, done: false};
  }
}

let matrix = Object.create(Matrix);
matrix.init(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);
for (let {x, y, value} of matrix) {
  console.log(x, y, value);
}
```

Any clue to where I maybe going wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting my Delegation Pattern code in the question I gained more clarity on concepts of Delegation Pattern flow. Refer [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)

The solution:

```
var Matrix = {
  init: function(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for(let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for(let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  },

  get: function(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
  },

  set: function(x, y, value) {
    this.content[y * this.width + x] = value;
  }
}

var MatrixIterator = {
  setup: function(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  },

  [Symbol.iterator]: function() {
    return this;
  },

  next: function() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true};

    let value = {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)
    };
    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return {value, done: false};
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(MatrixIterator, Matrix);

let matrix = Object.create(Matrix);

matrix.init(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);

let matrixIter = Object.create(MatrixIterator);

matrixIter.setup(matrix);

for (let {x, y, value} of matrixIter) {
  console.log(x, y, value);
}
```

The solution provided here can be improved further.

Comment: Instead of `Object.setPrototypeOf`,why don't you just do `class MatrixIterator extends Matrix`?

Comment: @JuanMendes I quote this from [link] (https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md)

" does JavaScript actually has classes? Plain and simple: No.

Since classes are a design pattern, you can, with quite a bit of effort, implement approximations for much of classical class functionality. JS tries to satisfy the extremely pervasive desire to design with classes by providing seemingly class-like syntax."

Comment: @JuanMendes In languages like JAVA, a class is instantiated into object form by a copy operation. Class inheritance implies copies. 

JS works opposite, it creates links between objects. Classes are plain and simple objects in JS.

Comment: @JuanMendes To answer your question, I chose not to go with Class Design Pattern( introduced in ECMAScript 2015) in JS.

Comment: It doesn't matter that they are not classes per se. It lets you do the same thing with cleaner syntax. I'd rather be a pragmatist than a purist. I find this style less readable than class syntax.